# The requested resource cannot be located for Preview in Notes Client

Tags: xpages

If I I have a blank xPage.  It works fine when Previewing with the browser but when I try to preview in the client, I am getting The requested resource cannot be located.

This occurs with any xPage.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is the error I am getting in the log.  It really does not tell me more than what the browser is telling me.

CLFAD0256E: Dispatcher Servlet Problem - Cannot find the module: pncpghd38.pncbank.com!!test/test2.nsf
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Cannot find the module: pncpghd38.pncbank.com!!test/test2.nsf
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Installation path (data inside program files), access rights, install failed. There are 1000 reasons. What does the logs say?

Comment: Have you referenced a file using the direct URL path? In the client it is not the same path to the root as you use in a URL. On my phone so can't do a link right now sorry :(

Comment: I am Previewing in the client from the designer

Comment: Does this app use the ext. library?  has that been installed correctly in the client?  It's kinda a pain.  There's the client install and then a second thing you need to do for web preview to work I believe.

Comment: If the XPage is blank maybe it is something outside of the XPage - like the theme for example which is causing the issue?

Comment: Bruce - the ones in workspace - there might be more than one - under data/domino for the preview

Comment: I updated my post above with the error I am getting in the log.

Comment: Can you verify: a) make the page not-blank (add a br tag :-)) b) does the ACL allow you access?